# Table spanning two columns creates hole in text

Tags: tables, two-column

I am writing an article in two columns:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{jarticle}
```

And at one point I include a table spanning 2 columns.

```
text before table

\begin{center}
\begin{table*}[ht]
...
\end{table*}
\end{center}

text after table
```

The table is placed at the top of the following page. This is fine.

What troubles me, that there are approximately 3 white lines between
`text before table` and `text after table`

Please, how can I remove this white space?

Comment: Don't encase the `table*` environment in a `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` construct. Instead, insert the command `\centering` immediately *after* the `\begin{table*}` instruction.

Comment: OK, I'll re-post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one encases a "floating object" (such as LaTeX `table`, `table*`, and `figure` objects) in a `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` construct, quite a bit of whitespace is inserted above and below the object. This may be desirable for other uses of the `center` environment, but not for the floats Instead, insert the command `\centering` immediately *after* the `\begin{table*}` instruction. The `\centering` command acts like a switch that's in effect until the end of the current environment is encountered (in the present case, a `table*` environment). That way, the contents of the `table*` environment will be horizontally centered, but without any extra vertical whitespace being inserted as well.

Hence, you may want to structure your code along the following lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{jarticle}
\begin{document}

text before table

\begin{table*} % no need to specify "[ht]"
\centering
...
\end{table*}


text after table
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining why this solves the problem.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen - Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated my answer quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I think this improves the answer for future generations....