# Table spanning two columns creates too many gaps

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, two-column, multicolumn

Firstly, I have gone through all questions related to this problem, including [Table spanning two columns creates hole in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/table-spanning-two-columns-creates-hole-in-text), and they have not provided me the solution I desire.

I have tried solutions including multicolumn, using different parameters for table, etc, none of which have worked for me.

I'm posting this question here out of desperation.

I would greatly obliged if you had a look at the mwd that I have displayed  below and give me a possible solution to my problem. I have changed my actual file and replaced the words in the table with 'Dummy' to maintain the table structure.

The .sty file 'eacl2017' that is used is located at http://eacl2017.org/index.php/calls/call-for-papers under 'SUBMISSION FORMAT'

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{eacl2017}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol, lipsum}

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

\title{Dummy}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1-1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Dummy}
\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{table*}[hbp]
\small
\begin{flushleft}
\caption{\label{table-4} \textit{Dummy for Dummy DummyDummy into Dummy DummyDummyDummy}}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{12cm}|}
\hline 
DummyDummyDummy (DummyDummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy) & DummyDummyDummy \\ 
\hline
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\item DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy (From Dummy)
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm} 
&
DummyDummyDummy \\
\hline
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item DummyDummyDummy Dummy DummyDummyDummy (From Dummy) 
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm} 
&
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
    \itemsep0em
    \item 
    If DummyDummyDummyDummy DummyDummyDummyDummy, Dummy as Dummy. If not, DummyDummy
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{enumerate}[i]
            \itemsep0em
            \item Dummy DummyDummy \textit{DummyDummyDummy}\textsuperscript{5} and Dummy Dummy Dummy \textit{Dummy} Dummy
            \item DummyDummyDummy Dummy DummyDummy \textit{Dummy}, or \textit{Dummy}.
        \end{enumerate}
        \vspace{-2mm}        
    \item 
    DummyDummyDummyDummy DummyDummyDummy
    \leftskip =0.2in
    DummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummy
    \leftskip =0.2in
    DummyDummyDummyDummyDummy DummyDummyDummy
    Dummy DummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy\textsuperscript{3} or Dummy DummyDummyDummy\textsuperscript{2} 
    DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy
    \leftskip=0in
    \item 
    If DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy, DummyDummy.
    \leftskip=0.2in
    Dummy --- The Dummy doesn`t DummyDummyDummyDummyDummy \textit{Dummy}, 
    such that Dummy Dummy is \textit{Dummy}, DummyDummyDummyDummyDummyDummy
    and DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy DummyDummy \textit{Dummy}.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\\
\hline
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\setcounter{enumi}{2}
\item DummyDummy DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummyDummyDummy DummyDummyDummy DummyDummyDummy
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm} 
& 
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
    \itemsep0em
    \item DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummyDummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummyDummyDummy
    \item If DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy, DummyDummyDummyDummy. Else DummyDummy
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{enumerate}[i]
            \itemsep0em
            \item The Dummy is in \textit{DummyDummyDummyDummy}\textsuperscript{5} and DummyDummy 
            \item The Dummy has Dummy Dummy DummyDummyDummy Dummy
        \end{enumerate}
        \vspace{-2mm}
    \item If DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummy
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{enumerate}[i]
        \itemsep0em
        \item The Dummy Dummy DummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy,
        \item The DummyDummy Dummy Dummy DummyDummy,
        \item An DummyDummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummy\textsuperscript{3} 
        or Dummy\textsuperscript{2} Dummy between Dummy 
        \item The DummyDummyDummy DummyDummy
        \item DummyDummy 
        \end{enumerate}
        \vspace{-2mm}
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\\
\hline
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
\item DummyDummy\textsuperscript{1} DummyDummy DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummyDummy DummyDummyDummy
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm} 
&
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
\itemsep-0.5em
\item If DummyDummyDummy Dummy DummyDummy Dummy. Else Dummy
    \begin{enumerate}[i]
    \itemsep0em
    \item The Dummy Dummy \textit{DummyDummy}\textsuperscript{5} and Dummy
    \textit{Dummy} or Dummy Dummy Dummy DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummy Dummy Dummy (for an Dummy Dummy Dummy\textsuperscript{1} Dummy DummyDummy) 
    \item There are DummyDummy DummyDummy \textit{Dummy} or \textit{Dummy}, Dummy DummyDummy
    \end{enumerate}
\item If the Dummy DummyDummy DummyDummy DummyDummy Dummy DummyDummyDummy
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3.5mm}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the table ends up right in the middle of the page, not allowing more text to come either above or below it as in this picture-

[image]

The previous and succeeding paras are pushed onto the above and below pages, wasting a LOT of space, something I desperately need.

Can anyone provide me with a solution to the problem such that the table is at the top of the page, and I can have text (in two-columns) below it, utilising the space as it should?

Comment: See this page: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat especially the part labeled **Details on the parameters that restrict/influence the placement**.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Thank you. I've tried using \intextsep after looking at the page again, but to no avail. It's exactly the same.

Comment: Is the `eacl2017` package available online so that your code can be tested?

Comment: Yes, I have already mentioned it in the question. The .sty file 'eacl2017' that is used is located at http://eacl2017.org/index.php/calls/call-for-papers under 'SUBMISSION FORMAT'

Comment: By the way, there is an error in the style file. At the end of the compilation, there is a warning `(\end occurred when \iffalse on line 331 was incomplete)`. Indeed, a '\fi` is missing but I was unable to determine the exact place. The author of the style file should be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force the `table*` environment to be at the top of a page containing some text at the bottom as well, I suggest you replace

```
\begin{table*}[hbp]
```

with

```
\begin{table*}[t!]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I was using [!htp] before, which wasn't working. But this does the trick.